# How do i move children objects to other parents?

Tags: blender

I was wondering if there was a way to move a child object to a new parent.

What i want to do is move the object in red in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPR5z.png) image moved and grouped like the one in the area in blue.

[image]

I would like it like this so that i can unwrap my entire project as a single object.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do was as easy as `CTRL+J`.